# C++ create a friend of a function?

Tags: c++, friend

So ive been asked to create a friend of a function for a university class and im a bit lost on the implementation. The question states "Add a function **showCat(Cat&)** as a friend of Cat.
This function should display the cat details in the same way as the **Cat::showCat()** function does"

The program is as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Cat
{
private:
   string name;
   string breed;
   int age;
   static constexpr double licenseFee = 10;

public:
   void setCatData(string, string, int);
   void showCat();
   friend void showCat(const Cat& cat); //friend function declaration
   
};

void Cat::setCatData(string catName, string catBreed, int catAge)
{
   name = catName;
   breed = catBreed;
   age = catAge;
}

void Cat::showCat(const Cat& aCat) //friend function definition
{
  cout << "Cat: " << aCat.name << " is a " << aCat.breed << endl;
  cout << "The cat's age is " << aCat.age << endl;
  cout << "License fee: $" << aCat.licenseFee << endl;
}

void Cat::showCat()
{
  cout << "Cat: " << name << " is a " << breed << endl;
  cout << "The cat's age is " << age << endl;
  cout << "License fee: $" << licenseFee << endl;
}

int main()
{
     Cat myCat;
     myCat.setCatData("Tigger", "Fluffy unit", 3);
     myCat.showCat();
     
}
```

The provided notes arent spectacular but this was my attempt based on the information provided to me. My attempt at the friend function can be seen in the declaration `friend void showCat(const Cat& cat);` in the public members of the cat class. The defintion can be seen as

```
void Cat::showCat(const Cat& aCat)
{
  cout << "Cat: " << aCat.name << " is a " << aCat.breed << endl;
  cout << "The cat's age is " << aCat.age << endl;
  cout << "License fee: $" << aCat.licenseFee << endl;
}
```

This where my errors stem from. On the line `void Cat::showCat(const Cat& aCat)` I get
`declaration is incompatible with "void Cat::showCat()" (declared at line 34)`

Im a bit lost to how friends operate so any help to fix my function/program would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration

```
friend void showCat(const Cat& cat);
```

declares `showCat(const Cat&)` as a *non* member function.

So you need to define it as such:

```
// Note that this is not a member function
void showCat(const Cat& aCat)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define friend function in such ways.

1. **Friend Function**:

define a function as friend of a class :

:

```
   friend void showCat(const Cat& cat);
```

and then implement this function independently not as a member of class.

```
       void showCat(const Cat& a)
       {
             cout << "Cat: " << a.name << " is a " << a.breed << endl;
             cout << "The cat's age is " << a.age << endl;
             cout << "License fee: $" << a.licenseFee << endl;
       }
```

2. **Define a function as friend for more than one class.**

   ```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    class Cat
    {
    private:
       string name;
       string breed;
       int age;
       static constexpr double licenseFee = 10;

    public:
       void setCatData(string, string, int);
       template<class A> friend void showAnimal(const A& a); //friend function declaration

    };

    class Mouse
    {
    private:
       string name;
       string breed;
       int age;
       static constexpr double licenseFee = 10;

    public:
       void setData(string, string, int);
       template<class A> friend void showAnimal(const A& a); //friend function declaration

    };
    void Cat::setCatData(string catName, string catBreed, int catAge)
    {
       name = catName;
       breed = catBreed;
       age = catAge;
    }
    void Mouse::setData(string mouseName, string mouseBreed, int mouseAge)
    {
       name = mouseName;
       breed = mouseBreed;
       age = mouseAge;
    }
    template<class A>
    void showAnimal (const A& a) //friend function definition
    {
            return;
    }
    template<>
    void showAnimal <Cat>(const Cat& a) //friend function definition
    {
      cout << "Cat: " << a.name << " is a " << a.breed << endl;
      cout << "The cat's age is " << a.age << endl;
      cout << "License fee: $" << a.licenseFee << endl;
    }

    template<>
    void showAnimal <Mouse>(const Mouse& a) //friend function definition
    {
      cout << "Cat: " << a.name << " is a " << a.breed << endl;
      cout << "The cat's age is " << a.age << endl;
      cout << "License fee: $" << a.licenseFee << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
         Cat myCat;
         myCat.setCatData("Tigger", "Fluffy unit", 3);
         showAnimal(myCat);

         Mouse myMouse;
         myMouse.setData("Tigger", "Fluffy unit", 3);
         showAnimal(myMouse);
    }
   ```
3. **Define a class as friend of another class:**

   ```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    class Cat
    {
    private:
       string name;
       string breed;
       int age;
       static constexpr double licenseFee = 10;

    public:
       void setCatData(string, string, int);
      friend class Show;
    };

    void Cat::setCatData(string catName, string catBreed, int catAge)
    {
       name = catName;
       breed = catBreed;
       age = catAge;
    }

   class Show
   {

   public:

       void showAnimal(const Cat& a)
       {
             cout << "Cat: " << a.name << " is a " << a.breed << endl;
             cout << "The cat's age is " << a.age << endl;
             cout << "License fee: $" << a.licenseFee << endl;
       }
   };

    int main()
    {
         Cat myCat;
         Show show;
         myCat.setCatData("Tigger", "Fluffy unit", 3);
         show.showAnimal(myCat);

    }
   ```
4. **define a member function of a class as friend for another class:**

   ```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
   class Cat;
   class Show
   {

   public:

       void showAnimal(const Cat& a);
   };
    class Cat
    {
    private:
       string name;
       string breed;
       int age;
       static constexpr double licenseFee = 10;

    public:
       void setCatData(string, string, int);
      friend void  Show::showAnimal(const Cat& a);
    };

    void Cat::setCatData(string catName, string catBreed, int catAge)
    {
       name = catName;
       breed = catBreed;
       age = catAge;
    }

       void Show::showAnimal(const Cat& a)
       {
             cout << "Cat: " << a.name << " is a " << a.breed << endl;
             cout << "The cat's age is " << a.age << endl;
             cout << "License fee: $" << a.licenseFee << endl;
       }

    int main()
    {
         Cat myCat;
         Show show;
         myCat.setCatData("Tigger", "Fluffy unit", 3);
         show.showAnimal(myCat);

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
void Cat::showCat(const Cat& aCat) //friend function definition
```

do:

```
void showCat(const Cat& aCat) //friend function definition



void  showCat(const Cat& aCat) //friend function definition
{
  cout << "Cat: " << aCat.name << " is a " << aCat.breed << endl;
  cout << "The cat's age is " << aCat.age << endl;
  cout << "License fee: $" << aCat.licenseFee << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer as the already existing one... but without explanation...